# Black line appears when updating a ListView with selected items

Tags: winapi, listview, visual-c++, activex

I have a list view that draws an additional black line when items in the list are modified and there are selected items in the list.
The code iterates over the list and updates the cells using the line of code below:

```
ListView_SetItem(m_hListCtrl, &lvItem);
```

Additional rows are added using the ListView_InsertItem macro.

If a row is added and there are other rows selected, the following happens:

[image: ListView with black line]

The line disappears if the user selects a different row. How can this black line be prevented/removed?

Comment: Are you calling [`DrawFocusRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162479.aspx) by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LVS_EX_GRIDLINES` style has a number of bugs associated with it that Microsoft have never bothered to fix, and this is one of them. The workaround is to forcibly redraw the list items when you make the particular changes that trigger the problem. You can redraw a range of list items using the `LVM_REDRAWITEMS` message, or even simpler just repaint the whole control with `InvalidateRect()`.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, unfortunately I cannot get InvalidateRect or redraw to remove the black line. Looks like I'm stuck with it for now!